# How to catch web api query params without values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have following method definition in a web api controller:

```
[Route("collections")]    
public HttpResponseMessage Collections(int c = 50, int p = 0)
```

and usually I call it like this

```
api/collections?count=10&page=0.
```

Are there any way to call that method as

```
api/collections?count&page
```

without getting BadRequest?

I think as "c" param has default value = 50 and "p" param has default value = 0 then api/collections?count&page should be transformed to api/collections?count=50&page=0. But asp.net web api didn't understand that.

Are there any way to make asp.net web api understand url api/collections?count&page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can make the params nullable and then call the action using a link like : `api/collections`

```
[Route("collections")]    
public HttpResponseMessage Collections(int? c = 50, int? p = 0)
```

but if you call it by `api/collections?count&page` the two parms will be null

Answer (score 0):

you can put two routes on the method

```
Route("Collections\count\{count}\page{page}")
Route("Collections\count\page")
```